# Issue with a drop down in R shiny

Tags: c, r, list, shiny, dashboard

I am currently in the process of building a dashboard in R shiny. I want the user to be able to select from a list of experiments which are currently live, which will change over time. Therefore it has to be called from a dataframe (or something similar) which is generated by the code each day as lists start and stop.

I have the current code below, however this provides a number rather than the name, which I assume is a reference to the name, but I cannot understand how to get it displaying the name. When I use the list code it does not run as it states I must individually list each item, (assuming this is like the one that works below for user type.

Testids is currently a dataframe with 45 obs. of 1 variable.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks in advance

```
library("shiny")
```

shinyUI(
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Draft dash"),
    # Sidebar with filters for test types

```
sidebarPanel(

  selectInput("Test", "Experiment Name:",
              c(Testids)          
              ),

  selectInput("User", "User Type:",
              list("All users" = "All",
                   "Known users" = "KN",
                   "Unknown users" = "UN",
                   "New users" = "NW",
                   "Existing users" = "EX")),
```

Comment: What data is in `Testids`? Is it the name of the tests? Where is it read into the app? - In `ui.r`? or `global.r`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `selectInput("Test", "Experiment Name:", c(Testids) )` will show the entries of dataframe `Testids` instead of the column names, which I think is what you want. Use `names(dataframe)` to populate the `SelectInput` list with the column names.

```
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    hist(mtcars[,input$Select], col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
   sidebarPanel(
     selectInput('Select', 'Selection:', names(mtcars)),
      selectInput("User", "User Type:",
          list("All users" = "All",
               "Known users" = "KN",
               "Unknown users" = "UN",
               "New users" = "NW",
               "Existing users" = "EX"))
                ),
    mainPanel(plotOutput("distPlot"))
  )
  ))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```